# Counting and storing a number of occurrences of one variable, based on another variable of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, iteration, func

```
Date         HomeTeam      AwayTeam        FTHG  FTAG FTR  
   <chr>      <chr>        <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1 08/10/2018 Man United   Leicester          2     1 H    
 2 08/11/2018 Bournemouth  Cardiff            2     0 H    
 3 08/11/2018 Fulham       Crystal Palace     0     2 A    
 4 08/11/2018 Huddersfield Chelsea            0     3 A    
 5 08/11/2018 Newcastle    Tottenham          1     2 A    
 6 08/11/2018 Watford      Brighton           2     0 H    
 7 08/11/2018 Wolves       Everton            2     2 D    
 8 08/12/2018 Arsenal      Man City           0     2 A    
 9 08/12/2018 Liverpool    West Ham           4     0 H
```

I'm trying to dynamically count the number of occurrences of each value possible in the FTR column ('H','A','D') for each team. The goal is to determine each team's record for the last 10 games. The league data is filtered by a certain date, so it's possible for a team to not have played 10 games at the requested date. This information (team's *Last10* record) will then be merged to a bigger table containing the team's stats. Therefore, I figured the easiest way to approach this would be to create a dataframe/tibble with the team's names in one column and their *Last10* record in a second column.

I've seen several solutions that count consecutively and by groups, but none that do it iteratively, with a limit, and stores it like I need. The result should look something like below.

```
1 Man United 6-1-3
2 Leicester  2-3-5
3 Arsenal    4-5-1
4 Man City   8-1-1
```

Comment: Isn't this a job for `xtabs`? Do you want the counts irrespective of whether it's home or away match?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes. For this post, home or away match is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your database is in the `df` `data.frame`, the code before produce a `data.frame` with four columns: `Teams`, `H`, `A` and `D` with the results of the last matches:

```
# Store the last 10 matches result of each team
# Check if there is a nicer way to obtain the names of all the teams
Last10 <- data.frame(Teams = names(table(rbind(df$HomeTeam, 
                                               df$AwayTeam))))
# Create empty columns to store results
Last10[,ncol(Last10)+c(1,2,3)] <- 0 
names(Last10) <- c("Teams","H", "D", "A")

MaxMatches <- 10 # Maximum number of last matches that would score
FilterDate <- df$Date[1:9] # Select which dates are taken into account
for (i in rev(which(df$Date %in% FilterDate))) { 
  # Go from the end date to the beginning
  # Check which teams have played
  teamindex <- which(Last10$Teams %in% df[i,c("HomeTeam","AwayTeam")])
  # Check if any of the teams have all the needed matches 
  teamscore <- rowSums(Last10[teamindex,c("H","D","A")])
  # If any teamscore is greater than the maximum number of matches
  # the scores should not be updated
  Last10$H[teamindex] <- Last10$H[teamindex] + 
    ifelse(teamscore < MaxMatches & df[i,"FTR"] == "H", 1, 0) 
  Last10$A[teamindex] <- Last10$A[teamindex] + 
    ifelse(teamscore < MaxMatches & df[i,"FTR"] == "A", 1, 0) 
  Last10$D[teamindex] <- Last10$D[teamindex] + 
    ifelse(teamscore < MaxMatches & df[i,"FTR"] == "D", 1, 0) 
}
```

If you want the three columns pasted togethers to look like `H-A-D` then you can use:

```
Last10$results <- apply(Last10[,c("H","D","A")], 1, paste, collapse = "-")
```

Comment: I've already filter the original dataframe for the date input. And I have a vector called "Team_Names" if that helps.

Comment: Also, I'm not looking at the last 10 games in general. I'm looking at the last 10 games PER TEAM. Whether they're the home or away team.

Comment: The code does not look for the last 10 games in general, it only update the H, D and A scores for each team if these scores sum less than 10. Due to the for loop going from the end to the beginning of the dates, the scores are updated with the last 10 matches of each team, and the other matches are not taken into account because the scores would sum up more than 10. 
Also, if you have already filter the dates you only have to change the `for` loop as `for (i in rev(1:nrow(df)))` and it would iterate over all rows of your filtered `data.frame`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the following bit of code does?
Last10$W[teamindex]

What does this return?

Comment: I don't know what `Last10$W[teamindex]` would return because there is no `W` column. However, `teamindex` is just the row index of the `Last10` `data.frame` for the Home team and Away team of each match. I use it to update the scores H, A and D of only the teams that have played the match in the date where is the iterator `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following does what the question asks for.
It uses `xtabs` to tabulate the columns of interest and then convert the result to class matrix.

```
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df1[c(2, 3, 6)], id.vars = "FTR")[-2]
res <- xtabs(~ value + FTR, df2)
dimnames(res) <- unname(dimnames(res))
rm(df2)

head(res)
#               A D H
#Arsenal        1 0 0
#Bournemouth    0 0 1
#Brighton       0 0 1
#Cardiff        0 0 1
#Chelsea        1 0 0
#Crystal Palace 1 0 0
```

To have a data.frame with the team names as a first column, just `cbind` the row names with the matrix.

```
res <- cbind.data.frame(Team_names = rownames(res), res)
rownames(res) <- NULL
head(res)
#      Team_names A D H
#1        Arsenal 1 0 0
#2    Bournemouth 0 0 1
#3       Brighton 0 0 1
#4        Cardiff 0 0 1
#5        Chelsea 1 0 0
#6 Crystal Palace 1 0 0
```

Comment: Getting closer. I pulled the league stats from my function from another part of the project, which I know is correct because I verified it manually in Excel. The first set is the output from your "res". The second is what it should be.

Comment: A D H
Arsenal        5 3 5
Bournemouth    5 2 7
Brighton       3 3 8
Burnley        5 3 6
Cardiff        4 2 8
Chelsea        4 4 5
Crystal Palace 6 3 5
Everton        2 4 7
Fulham         3 2 8
Huddersfield   6 4 4
Leicester      5 3 6
Liverpool      5 3 5
Man City       4 2 8
Man United     4 4 6
Newcastle      7 3 4
Southampton    3 6 5
Tottenham      9 0 4
Watford        5 2 7
West Ham       6 3 5
Wolves         5 4 5

Comment: Team Record
1         Arsenal  8-2-3
2     Bournemouth  6-6-2
3        Brighton  5-6-3
4         Burnley  2-9-3
5         Cardiff  3-9-2
6         Chelsea  8-1-4
7  Crystal Palace  3-8-3
8         Everton  6-3-4
9          Fulham  2-9-2
10   Huddersfield  2-8-4
11      Leicester  6-5-3
12      Liverpool 10-0-3
13       Man City 12-0-2
14     Man United  6-4-4
15      Newcastle  3-8-3
16    Southampton  1-7-6
17      Tottenham 10-3-0
18        Watford  6-6-2
19       West Ham  4-7-3
20         Wolves  4-6-4

Comment: This is my first post on SO so if there's a better way to post this data, please inform me.